# How can I freeze ubuntu dependencies so that my repository is reproducible?

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration

I have some software I developed on ubuntu 14.04. It was green in the CI and I did a release.

Fast forward 4 months, I open a new PR, and it's red. Apparently apt-get updates the packages, something has changed since the release, and now my release does not build anymore.

While I understand the need to move forward against the changed apt dependencies, I am also in the situation where my releases rot quickly as the platform is updated. Is there a way of freezing the apt dependencies to the specific moment where the release is done, so that I am always guaranteed to build against the same environment?

Comment: Use conda as your package manager to create reproducible environments. https://github.com/conda/conda

Comment: @NehalJWani what does a python package manager have to do with apt dependencies?

Comment: It is not a python package manager. It provides a lot of non-python packages too (like gcc, libevent etc). I am asking you to move away from apt and use packages from conda. List of packages on the default channel: https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/repodata.json